# Import all files from a framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, import, header

Is there a way to import all files from a framework, and not just the specific headers you want? This may seem inefficient, but I was just curious if this was possible?

Answer (score 6):

Apple's convention is to use a header within the framework which has the same name as the framework:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> // << imports all public headers of Foundation.framework
```

If the framework in question does not include such a file, you can always write your own.

Even better, you can use modules, which use the syntax: `@import Foundation;`. This is similar to `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`, but uses a much improved compilation model.

Note: Modules are presently supported in Xcode for Apple's frameworks, although support for user-defined module maps exists in clang. So, hopefully we can define our own modules soon.

Comment: I was about to comment about `@import`. +1 It may be also worth noting that it can be currently used for Apple's frameworks only

Comment: @GabrielePetronella thanks :) added a note at the same point you edited.